# Spring @Value does not load properties

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration

I have two classes which both use configuration properties.

This one loads

```
package com.cegeka.campus;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/outlook")
public class OutlookController
{
    @Value("${frontend.url}")
    private String frontendUrl;
    .....
}
```

But this one returns null:

```
package com.cegeka.campus;

public class AuthHelper
{
    @Value("${backend.authorize.url}")
    private static String redirectUrl;
    ...
}
```

Our main class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.cegeka.campus")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.cegeka.campus")
@EntityScan("com.cegeka.campus")
public class CampusApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(CampusApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Why can't I load backend.authorize.url? The @Value simply doesn't inject.

The properties file (application.yml) looks like this:

```
frontend:
  url: http://hi02549:8080/courseka
backend:
  authorize:
    url: http://hi02549:8080/campus/api/outlook/authorize
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two issues in the class AuthHelper:

1. AuthHelper should be a Spring managed bean and have `@Component` annotation.
2. Field `redirectUrl` is static and cannot be injected. The solution is either make the field non static or

```java
private static String redirectUrl;

@Value("${backend.authorize.url}")
public void setRedirectUrl(String url) {
    redirectUrl = url;
}
```

Comment: Your sir, are a hero.

Answer (score 0):

add this method and try again :

```
@Bean 
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```